# Seafarers - Ships over Ports?

Tags: catan, catan-seafarers

Quick question about seafarers. Ports are added onto the map by placing them alongside the edge of a hex. Once a port is there is it right to consider that edge as Coastal or not? i.e. Can a ship be built along that edge?

Comment: Which scenario are you playing?  Most scenarios specify the location of the ports.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A port is coastal.

A ship can be build if a settlement or city is present (or as a continuation of other ships).